# Does the derivative of $f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x}{2}+x^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)& x\neq 0,\\0, &x=0\end{cases}$ exist everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, functions

I'm trying to prove that

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x}{2}+x^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)& x\neq 0,\\0, &x=0.\end{cases}$$

has a derivative everywhere. Here is what I have done:

Let $x_0\in\Bbb{R}-\{0\}$ where $x\neq x_0$

$$\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\dfrac{\left[\dfrac{x}{2}+x^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\right]-\left[\dfrac{x_0}{2}+x_0^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right)\right]}{x-x_0}$$

$$=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{x-x_0}{2}\right)  + x^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-x^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right)}{x-x_0}$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2}+\left(x+x_0\right) \sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+x^2\left[2\sin\left(\dfrac{x-x_0}{2}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{x+x_0}{2}\right)\right].$$

So, attaching limit

$$f'(x_0)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\dfrac{1}{2}+2\,x_0 \sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right).$$

Hence, $f$ has a derivative everywhere, since the case of $x=0$ is obvious. But I have not tried it.

Questions:

1. Am I right?
2. How do I get an open interval containing $x=0$ in which $f(x)$ is increasing?

Comment: You've got that the case of $x_0 = 0$ is obvious and worked through the $x_0\neq 0$ case, but I'd argue that's backwards! The $x_0 \neq 0$ case is clearly differentiable since it is a sum/product/composition of differentiable functions. $x_0=0$ is where the actual struggle is.

Comment: @B. Mehta: Is that true?

Comment: @Mike Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

For $x\neq 0$ let derive $f(x)$ according to the expression given.

For $x=0$ let apply the definition of derivative by limit of the incremental ratio at $x=0$, that is

$$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

As noted in the comments, since $f’(x)=1/2 +2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ for $x\to 0$ the derivative oscillates between $-\frac12$ and $\frac 32$ therefore there is no interval containing $0$ with $f$ monotone.

Comment: Can you please, elaborate further?

Comment: I meant the second question!

Comment: You can use that $f’(x)\ge0 \implies f$ is increasing.

Comment: @ gimusi : My problem is that $x\in\Bbb{R}$ not $x\in\Bbb{R^+}.$ So, that's posing challenge at me. So, $f'(x)\geq 0$ might be a challenge.

Comment: Since $f’(x)=1/2 +2x\sin(1/x)-cos(1/x)$ it seems we cannot find an interval such that $f’(x)\ge0$ and the $f$ increasing.

Comment: From the expression for $f'(x) $ given in your comment it is clear that as $x\to 0$ the derivative $f'(x) $ oscillates between $(1/2)-1=-1/2$ and $(1/2)+1=3/2$ and hence every interval containing $0$ has points where derivative is negative (and also points where $f'$ is positive). Thus there is no interval containing $0$ where $f$ is monotone.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes indeed you are right, I add that point! Thanks